# Bootstrap dropdown-menu alignment fail if image_tag has a class="center-block"

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

```
    <ul class="logo">
         <li class="navtabs dropdown">
           <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            <%= image_tag('Thumbnailimagestufffurrreal.jpg', class: "center-block") %>
           </a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="theproblemdropdown" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
             <li class=""><%= link_to "Rails", jobs_path %></li>
             <li class=""><%= link_to "Scrape", contracts_path %></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
    </ul>
```

So The problem is that the image is centered in the page but the drop down is not.
I have tried almost everything but in the end complete fail.

center-block class on the ul#theproblemdropdown made the dropdown always visible and it still did not center it.

Center-text which has worked in a few cases before does not seem to work here.
I read an answer by someone else that tried making an encompasing div with a relative position and say the dropdown-menu ul as absolute positioning however it has not worked for me.

A reference to the page so people can take a look at the direct problem:http://www.railsjobhub.com/
As I said in a comment below I think the culprit is that while the image is centered the link seems to span the entire page width.

Any ideas anyone?

Edit:
Thanks to Ronan Louarn below it got me thinking of a work-around. It is not perfect but they are now aligned with the image on dropdown. The problem was that the li.dropdown was taking up the width of the page. So I first made the ul.logo col-xs-12 then made the li col-xs-2 with an offset of 5. The li is technically smaller than the logo image which gets it pretty close to centering if not exactly perfect.

```
   <ul class="logo col-xs-12">
       <li class="dropdown col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-5">
         <a id="dLabel" data-target="#" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <%= image_tag('ThumbRailsJobHub.jpg', class: "center-block") %>
         </a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu col-xs-12 text-center" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
           <li class=""><%= link_to "Jobs", jobs_path %></li>
           <li class=""><%= link_to "Contracts", contracts_path %></li>
         </ul>
       </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you should use this method:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a id="dLabel" data-target="#" href="http://example.com" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown trigger
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>

  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

This in javascript tab on bootstrap site.
[image]

Comment: So I did try what you suggested, still the same problem what I did notice though is that even though i'm centering say the image the "tag" or clickable link spans the entire page width. This is most likely the culprit. Just a reference for you and others this is the page i'm trying to do it on: http://www.railsjobhub.com/       right on the logo in the middle of the page

Comment: try to add class: 'col-xs-12'  - > to your ul dropdown-menu.

Comment: Unfortunately that just gets the menu to also be clickable across the entire width of the page but does not align it. Maybe I should just create a fake group of navtabs until the logo is centered in the center of the page. Thank you so much for your time and effort!